# Count Category From Column

Tags: sql-server

I have some table, which I want count column that column have 2 category, the explain table like this:

[image]

I have query with union like this:

```
select CLASS, BRANCH, COUNT(STATUS) as STATUS
from dwh.Table a
where STATUS = 'INCLUDE'
group by CLASS, BRANCH, STATUS
order by CLASS

union

select CLASS, BRANCH, COUNT(STATUS) as STATUS
from dwh.Table a
where STATUS = 'NOT INCLUDE'
group by CLASS, BRANCH, STATUS
order by CLASS
```

but I have got some error.

Comment: *"but I have got some error"* And what is that error? Why are both aggregating *and* grouping on the column `STATUS`? Normally you would aggregate *or* group on the column.

Comment: Please add your sample data as text, not as image !!

Comment: I'm so sorry for my mistake. but the image can provide complete my question in detail. thanks before

Comment: No, the image only frustrates people who want to help you, because now we have to type over the information in the image into our test table, and when you provide the same information as text we can copy/paste. The same information as text will not only provide us with the same complete information to complete your question, it will also make live easier for us to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT
    CLASS,
    BRANCH,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'INCLUDE'     THEN 1 END) AS [INCLUDE],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'NOT INCLUDE' THEN 1 END) AS [NOT INCLUDE]
FROM dwh.Table
GROUP BY
    CLASS,
    BRANCH;
```

If you just want to report classes only, then simply group by the class by itself (and also select only the class):

```sql
SELECT
    CLASS,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'INCLUDE'     THEN 1 END) AS [INCLUDE],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'NOT INCLUDE' THEN 1 END) AS [NOT INCLUDE]
FROM dwh.Table
GROUP BY
    CLASS;
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `group by` and `count` can do that

```
select t.class,
       count(case when t.status = 'INCLUDE' then 1 end) as INCLUDE,
       count(case when t.status = 'NOT INCLUDE' then 1 end) as [NOT INCLUDE]
from   test t
group by t.class
```

Test it yourself [in this DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4bebae86a0eba5486ab0d304b3140bdc)

That will leave a warning though

> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET
> operation.

---

So another way to do it is `group by` and `sum` and this way you will not get a warning anymore

```
select t.class,
       sum(case when t.status = 'INCLUDE' then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when t.status = 'NOT INCLUDE' then 1 else 0 end)
from   test t
group by t.class
```

See the [altered DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e891d3f3eb401714dc8ea791fc1895e0)